# DataTables convert incoming epoch date to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: datatables

I am using an AJAX call with datatables to populate a table. The format of the incoming data is:

```
{
"name": "John Doe",
"date":1244231200500
}
```

I can see that date formatting is discussed here: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18 but there's no clear instructions for epoch data conversion.

What I want to do is put something (like within the example at the datatables site) like:

```
  $.fn.dataTable.moment('epoch');
```

...but I don't see an option. What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you include [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) you can sort this out quite easily using moment within a `render` function of your [`columns` option array](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns). Something like this should work:

```
{
    "data":"date",
    "render": function(data){
        return moment.unix(data).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's almost there, but it looks like my unix date might be in a different format. For example, I just tried with 1447160400000 and I got 09/09/47828 but I should've got 10/11/2015.

Comment: Oddly enough it seems to work when I remove unix and use: return moment(data).format("DD/MM/YYYY"). I don't understand why

Comment: Your date might be in milliseconds.  If so, divide by 1000.

Comment: instead of moment.unix() you can use moment.utc() for epoch in millis

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own formatting function:

```
function ISODateString(d) {
    function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n }
    return pad(d.getDate()) + '/' + pad(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
}
```

And call it in datatables render:

```
"render": function(data){
    var d = new Date(parseInt(data.substr(6), 0));
    return ISODateString(d);
}
```

Comment: Good solution for those who don't want to use moment.js file